# Suggestions for a Mountain Witch follow-up?

Tags: game-recommendation

We played a one-shot of Mountain Witch and some people have expressed interest in a similar game but whe don't feel like just reshuffling the dark destinies. Has anybody written similar scenarios or continued a game that started as a Mountain Witch game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two games, [*Cold City* and its follow-up *Hot War*](http://www.contestedground.co.uk/), draw heavily from *The Mountain Witch*. You could even say they're extended hacks for handling the fiction of a very different time and place.

Answer (score 2):

If your players really liked the trust mechanic, [*Apocalypse World*](http://apocalypse-world.com/) uses something very similar. If they really liked the setting, perhaps [*Kagematsu*](http://sites.google.com/site/creamaliengames/Home/kagematsu-the-rpg)? Although that's a one-shot game as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.story-games.com/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=6644&page=1) is a report of a game which used the rules from *The Mountain Witch* for an *Apocalypse Now* type of game. There's enough detail to enable you to recreate it, I should think.

Alternatively, I'd second C. Edwards and suggest *Cold City*, which is a similar sort of thing, and a very good game in its own right.

Comment: Wow, this report is awesome.